# How to create PDF vector icons without Illustrator

Tags: macos, icons, inkscape

I want to make some vector icons in PDF format for use in buttons and such on Mac OS X. Apparently most people use Illustrator for that, but what if I don't have Illustrator?

I tried using Inkscape, but when I save as PDF there is always an opaque white background. Saving as .eps or .ps and converting with Preview did no better.

Edit: Why PDF? Because Apple recommends it for toolbar and sidebar icons.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000967-TP6

Comment: It would help to understand why you need a clear PDF file. Knowing that, there's probably a solution more appropriate than Inkscape for your particular purpose.

Comment: Apple suggests using PDF icons for toolbar icons and such, in anticipation of high-resolution screens.

Comment: I'm using Inkscape 0.44.1 from 2006 and it has an option to save as "PDF with transparency". Seems to work correctly. Does your not have that option?

Comment: Good point, deleted my answer.

Comment: I'm using Inkscape 0.48. I don't see a "PDF with transparency" option. I asked on xcode-users@lists.apple.com, and so far people have suggested OmniGraffle, Intaglio, and Opacity.

Comment: I just tried it on 0.48.1. It's just "PDF" on that version and it appears that empty areas are transparent. Try it.